# Scheduler Javascript Library / Component that works in Salesforce Lightning with LockerService

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, locker-service

Please, could someone recommend a Scheduler Javascript Library / Component which will works in Salesforce Lightning with LockerService?

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Standard Agenda View**

Using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io) javascript component.

You need to add these static resources:

- jQuery 3.3.1
- Moment JS 2.22.0
- FullCalendar 3.9.0
- FullCalendar Scheduler 1.9.4

**Lightning Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">

    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                           $Resource.FullCalenderJs + '/jquery.min.js',
                           $Resource.FullCalenderJs + '/moment.min.js',
                           $Resource.FullCalenderJs + '/fullcalendar.min.js',
                           $Resource.FullCalenderJs + '/scheduler.min.js'  
                           )}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />

    <link href="{!$Resource.fullcalendar_min_css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{!$Resource.fullcalendar_scheduler_min_css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="{!$Resource.fullcalendar_print_min_css}" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />

    <div class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium">
        <div aura:id="calendar"></div>
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

**Controller JS:**

```
({
    afterScriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.loadCalendar(component);
    }
})
```

**Helper JS:**

The key here is to set the **defaultView** to **agendaWeek** this will give you a scheduler/agenda layout

```
({
    loadCalendar : function(component) {             
        // get data
        var data;

        var ele = component.find('calendar').getElement();
        $(ele).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'agendaWeek,listWeek'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            minTime: '06:00:00',
            maxTime: '22:00:00',
            height: "auto",
            events: data,
            businessHours: [
                {
                    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Fri
                    start: '09:00', 
                    end: '17:00', 
                },
                {
                    dow: [ 6, 0 ], // Sat & Sun
                    start: '10:00',
                    end: '15:00', 
                }
            ]
        });
    }
})
```

It should look something like this:

[image]

If you want a timeline view, add the **paid for** [Scheduler](https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler) addon

Use the same Lightning Component and Controller JS code, but use this Javascript to load the calendar:

**Scheduler Helper JS:**

Notice the **defaultView** is set to **timelineDay** and **resourceGroupField** is **true** and **resources** is defined.

```
({
    loadCalendar : function(component) {             
        // get some data here
        var data;      
        var ele = component.find('calendar').getElement();
        $(ele).fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                right: 'timelineDay,timelineWeek'
            },
            defaultView: 'timelineDay',
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            minTime: '06:00:00',
            maxTime: '22:00:00',
            height: "auto",
            resourceGroupField: 'venue',
            resources: [
                { id: 'a', venue: 'Bristol', title: 'Person A' },
                { id: 'b', venue: 'Bristol', title: 'Person B' },
                { id: 'c', venue: 'London', title: 'Person C' },
                { id: 'd', venue: 'London', title: 'Person D' }
            ],            
            events: data,
            businessHours: [
                {
                    dow: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ], // Monday - Fri
                    start: '09:00', 
                    end: '18:00', 
                },
                {
                    dow: [ 6, 0 ], // Sat & Sun
                    start: '10:00',
                    end: '15:00', 
                }  
            ]
        });
    }
})
```

And the timeline view should look like this:

[image]

Comment: @Robs nice work. Thanks for sharing this with the community. Can you also please include the version information for the libraries you used?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question has an accepted answer I would like to give an alternative recommendation that is not a calendar but a scheduler based on resources and events/tasks. Depending on your needs it might or might not be a better fit.

It is a newly released, paid for component that ships with an integration demo for Salesforce Lightning, read more here:

- [Bryntum Scheduler](https://www.bryntum.com/products/scheduler/)

**Disclaimer: I am one of the authors**
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you checked it work inside of [Salesforce LockerService](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm)?