# Build a Custom Calendar in Lightning

Tags: lightning, calendar, public-calendar

My client has a requirement to build a Lightning Calendar. The 'outofthebox' calendar will not satisfy our requirements. We would need something which has excel like format with rows as "projects assigned to a resource" and columns as "Dates of current week". 
Can someone please point me in some direction to start with?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a GANTT CHART. Please check if this works for you [Google Chart Gantt](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart) or [JQuery Gantt Charts](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/434/top-5-best-free-jquery-and-javascript-dynamic-gantt-charts-for-web-applications). I am not sure if they are compatible with lightning.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best solution would be to use an external JavaScript calendar library.

Have a look at [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) - it is open source and supported by LockerService.

You can also read [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214108/scheduler-javascript-library-component-that-works-in-salesforce-lighting-with) answer to see how to add FullCalendar to your component and you can see [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/comparison-javascript-calendars-schedulers/) article that compares 3 different JavaScript 
 calendar libraries (I do not know if the other ones are supported by LockerService)